# Overlay Two ggplot in Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a very large dataset that I'm plotting on Shiny using ggplot. I have a a slider tied to the values on x axis with which I would like to recolor the selected subset of the data and let the rest of the data remain as is.

The simplest option is to recreate the entire plot but since it's a large dataset it's a very slow process. As an alternative, I was considering letting the original plot stay as is, and putting another plot on top of it with the `plot.background = 'none'` and just the coloured points. I'm unable to achieve this with the `renderPlot` in the `server.r` and `plotOutput` in the `ui.r` -

server.r:

```
output$Plot1= renderPlot({
   ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = wt))
})

output$Plot2= renderPlot({
       ggplot(mtcars[mtcars$mpg > 15,]) + geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = wt), color = 'Efficient')
})
```

ui.r (I don't know how to fit Plot2 in this):

```
fluidRow(
               class = 'Plot1Row',
               column(
                  plotOutput(
                     "Plot1", 
                     width = '100%'
                  ),
                  width = 12
               )
            )
```

Any tips?

Comment: It might be a better idea to modify the plot using grid functions. (Please provide a reproducible example ...)

Comment: Could you point me to the grid function? I'm adding a toy chart in the meantime.

Comment: Do you consider `ggvis` as an option?

Comment: I did but since ggvis is still in development, I didn't want to tie myself to it.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Related new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55201041/shiny-reactive-only-for-one-part-of-a-plot-only

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example explaining my comment:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars[mtcars$mpg > 15,]) + geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = wt), color = 'green')
p    

#produce an otherwise identical gtable with a subset of points with different color 
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars[mtcars$mpg > 15,]) + geom_blank(aes(x = mpg, y = wt), color = 'green') +
  geom_point(data = mtcars[mtcars$mpg > 25,], aes(x = mpg, y = wt), color = 'blue')
g1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))

library(gtable)
#find the correct viewport
seekViewport(grid.grep("panel", grep = TRUE)$name)
#draw just the points 
grid.draw(gtable_filter(g1, "panel")$grobs[[1]]$children$geom_point.points)
```

[image: resulting plot]

This doesn't redraw the complete plot. Since I'm not a shiny user, you'll have to test yourself how to do this in shiny.

Comment: This is specifically interacting with the display and adding another layer on top of it, right? This isn't modifying the plot itself?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you mean by "plot itself". If you want to remove something, you need to redraw the plot (at least that's what I believe. I'm not an expert regarding the grid package).

Comment: Thanks, @Roland. I will check whether this work on Shiny too (although I think it's unlikely). If it does, then the accepted checkmark is all yours.