# Shiny reactive only for one part of a plot only

Tags: r, shiny

I have a little problem in Shiny achieving a plot where one part reacts to one input and another one reacts to another input.

Generally speaking, my code follows this scheme:

```
output$a<-renderPlot({

plot(input$x)
points(input$y)

})
```

Problem is, every time x or y change, the entire plot is re-rendered, i would like to, somehow, make them "independent", redrawing x only when x changes and no when y changes too.

I've been reading about reactive(), but in this case both commands must be in the same output plot, so, can't take one out of output$a.

Any ideas?

Comment: Would like to know this too, here is related post with no answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746962/overlay-two-ggplot-in-shiny

Comment: I found a better approach, renderCachedPlot() can be used to force a section to remain not rendered unless an specific variables changes, but the problem is that the plot size can't be controlled (not sure yet, still reading about it..)